# Cannot Make MudBlazor MudTextField Mask Work Properly

Tags: .net, razor, blazor, mask, mudblazor

I have an Application in Blazor, using MudBlazor. In this application, I need an TextField that modifies his Mask according to the user Input. I need to modify when the numbers amount is higher then x.

Example:

1234.1234.12-2 for inputs with 11 or less numbers;
123.456.789/123-456 for inputs with more than 11 numbers;

The thing is, the PatternMasks limits me to the first input (the less one, that I want to be the first). So I put the mask higher:

```
MultiMask multiMask = new MultiMask("0000.0000.00-00", new MaskOption("second", "000.000.000/000-000", @"^([0-9./-]{12,})"));
```

But, the problem is, when it is changing from "0000.0000.00-00" to "000.000.000/000-000", it is perfect, but, when I am erasing, trying to go back to the original, the Text Field and Mask value changes, but do not show how it is stored. It stays 123.412.341/22 when it should be 1234.1234.12.2.

Here is my Code:

```
<MudTextField T="string" bind-value="@register.Number"
        Label="Order/Id"
        Required="true"
        Mask=@multiMask>
</MudTextField>

@code{
      MultiMask multiMask = new MultiMask("0000.0000.00-00", new MaskOption("second", "000.000.000/000-000", @"^([0-9./-]{12,})"));
}
```

I've already tried almost everything. Forcing Update via code (referencing the MudTextField), using ValueChanged to update, etc. I only achieved with two MudTextFields, separated by an if statement. The problem with this solution is that when changes, it goes out of focus. Maybe I can implement a custom script to handle this, but I think it is better to just use the Mask.

Any Help would be great;